# How to bind data from Entity model to DropDown in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

HI all i have table with EmployeeDetails,this is my linq query for geting requried columns from table...now i want to bind this data to DropDown how can i do this

```
 var EmployeeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>().Select(e => new
        {
           id=e.EmployeId,
          Name = e.EmployeeName
        }).ToList();
```

this is my controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {                       
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a model to you view. Only this way you can bind any data to dropdownlist.
Take a look at [this article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ViewModel really..

So something like this..

Employee details DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDetails 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

View model a little like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public EmployeeDetails EmployeeDetails {get;set;}
}
```

Your action might look a little like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{                       
    //Setup a viewmodel
    var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
    viewModel.EmployeeDetails = //your query to get employee details
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then in the view you can do something a little like this:

```
@model {fullnamespace}.EmployeeViewModel

<select>
    <option> --- Select Option --- </option>
@foreach (var employeeDetail in Model.EmployeeDetails)
{
    <option value="@employeeDetail.Id">@employeeDetail.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: Be advised I typed this into the browser not VS so it might not be exactly right, should get you going though.